# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/next/dist/client/next.js' in 'D:\GitHub\project'

Tags: node.js, next.js

This happens when I try to run `next build` on my new windows laptop.

`C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/next/dist/client/next.js` does exist, but it was trying a wrong routing by reading it in D:/github/project.

Is there a way I can let next.js know it is getting into the wrong route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running this command solves my problem:

`npx next build`

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked when I deleted the ./next dir and ran `yarn install` or `npm i` (Depending On Your Package Manager)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You mean `.next` dir? So you are reinstalling the dependencies and rebuild the project in the same flow, I guess.

Comment: Yes, Pretty Much